# How do I serialize a complex Map object?

Tags: java, serialization, hashmap

I have to pass an object across a system where I can only transmit strings. Serialization is perfect for what I need but I can't get this metrics object to serialize properly.

Java creating the object:

```
Map<String, HashMap<String, String>> metrics = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();
String serializedObject = "";
            try {
                 ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                 ObjectOutputStream so = new ObjectOutputStream(bo);
                 so.writeObject(metrics);
                 so.close();
                 serializedObject = bo.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                 System.out.println(e);
            }
```

…pass serializedObject as a String…

Java desterilizing the object back into a metrics object.

```
Map<String, HashMap<String, String>> metrics = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();

try {
                 byte b[] = serializedObject.getBytes(); 
                 ByteArrayInputStream bi = new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
                 ObjectInputStream si = new ObjectInputStream(bi);
                 metrics = (Map<String, HashMap<String, String>>) si.readObject();
                 si.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                 System.out.println(e);
            }
```

I don't get errors but printing out the bytes of the serialized object show that it's way too small to be the data I'm serializing.

Comment: Instead of printing the bytes, why not print the Map before serializing it, and after deserializing it, instead of guessing if it's too small or not? Or even better, test that bot are equal. Also, have you read the javadoc of ByteArrayOutputStream.toString()? Does it seem like a good idea to use that method with arbitrary bytes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are mapping `byte[]` to `String` using `toString()` and `getBytes()`. That won't work, your serialized data will get corrupted because this `String` methods are not designed to handle random byte sequences.

If you need to transfer `byte[]` around write it and read it using [`InputStream.read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read()) and [`OutputStream.write()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write(int)). For example, simply passing the `byte[]` around with `new ByteArrayInputStream(bo.toByteArray())` it will work:

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> metrics = new HashMap<>();
metrics.put("test", new HashMap<>());

ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

ObjectOutputStream so = new ObjectOutputStream(bo);
so.writeObject(metrics);
so.close();

ByteArrayInputStream bi = new ByteArrayInputStream(bo.toByteArray());
ObjectInputStream si = new ObjectInputStream(bi);
Map<String, Map<String, String>> result = (Map<String, Map<String, String>>) si.readObject();
si.close();

System.out.println(result.equals(metrics)); // true
```

Comment: the bo.toByteArray() is there a way to send this as a String? I'm using Hadoop Map/Reduce and I can only send a string in my environment.

Comment: @JoshuaHedges you can encode it as Base64 string if you have to pass a string.

Comment: @JoshuaHedges - Hadoop does have a BytesWritable class you can use for arbitrary byte[] data - https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/index.html?org/apache/hadoop/io/BytesWritable.html

Comment: I'm passing this sterilized object in as a property to the Map reduce job with the conf.set("property-name", serializedMap). I get the data from a webservice. I'm in Java 7 so I have to use DataTypeConverter to do the "Base64" conversion. I see the long encryption string. I think I'm getting close. Thanks for the help man.

Comment: Have you considered converting your Map into a JsonString?